# How to determine the date of a given day of the week?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Given `February` and `6` (the integer for Sunday in Python), how can I get the specific date of the first Sunday of February? I know how I can get whether it is Sunday, (

```py
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
```

), but I want the program to almost work this backwards.

Example code:

`date = datetime.date.toDate(day, month, year, which_week)`
`date = datetime.date.toDate(6, 2, 2021, 0) # Sunday, February, 2021, First Week`

Example output:
`February 7 # (as an example for this year).`

Comment: Could you perhaps show an example input and expected output?

Comment: Well, you can see what week day is the first day in the month, right? I should be easy after that. Eg. if the first day is Friday, you'll know that Sunday is the 3rd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to calculate the weekday for the first day of a given month. Then add a calculated number of days for a specified weekday. For February 2019, the 3rd is the first Sunday:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_date(month, year, day_num):
    """Get date of first specified day given month and year."""
    first_date = date(year, month, 1)
    first_day = first_date.weekday()
    day_inc = day_num + (7 if first_day > day_num else 0) - first_day
    return first_date + timedelta(days=day_inc)

date = get_date(2, 2019, 6)  # 6 represents Sunday
# datetime.date(2019, 2, 3)
```